# How to keep padding on multiple images with hover effect when screen sizes change

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images with the same hover effect and same padding, it looks fine when my screen is full size. The 2 screens I am referencing are my normal 24 inch screen, and my smaller 13 inch laptop. Whenever I look at it on my 13in screen the padding goes away and all 4 images are together with no padding. How do I keep the padding no matter the screen size? The code works for mobile how I want it to just not for medium size screens. Sorry I am very new to all of this and don't really know what I am doing.

```css
.team-area {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 100px;
}

.single-team {
  width: 360px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}

.single-team:hover {
  transform: translateY(15px);
}

.single-team:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.single-team:hover .team-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.single-team::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, transparent);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.single-team img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.single-team .team-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(60px);
  transition: .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .team-area {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
  }
  .single-team {
    padding: 50px;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .singleteam img {
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="team-area">
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index1.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>Before</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index2.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>After</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index3.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>Before</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index4.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>After</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a margin to your `.single-team` class. There is space between the images on a larger screen because you have the parent as a flexbox with `justify-content: space-around;` Without a margin, they will touch each other once the screen width is small enough.

```css
.team-area {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 100px;
}

.single-team {
  width: 360px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 10px;              /* example margin value */
}

.single-team:hover {
  transform: translateY(15px);
}

.single-team:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.single-team:hover .team-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.single-team::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, transparent);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.single-team img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.single-team .team-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(60px);
  transition: .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .team-area {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
  }
  .single-team {
    padding: 50px;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .singleteam img {
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="team-area">
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index1.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>Before</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index2.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>After</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index3.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>Before</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single-team">
    <img class="image__img" src="./index4.jpg" alt="picture">
    <div class="team-text">
      <h2>After</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is responsive design. Responsive design is when the page styling changes with the size of the page. The simplest way to achieve a semi-responsive webpage is to use relative units like % vw and vh, like you have. That’s why it looks good on several screen sizes. But at a certain point, you need to redesign certain aspects of the styling. This is where @media comes in. I could explain it in detail, but MDN already did that quite sufficiently: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media.